# Summation of two monotonic function with different types (increasing and decreasing) is a monotonic function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I would appreciate it if someone helps me  with the following question.

Suppose $a,b∈R+$. We have $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. Also, $h(x)$ is a monotonic function on $[0,b]$,   $f(x)=a-\frac{a}{b}x$, $g(0)=0$ and g(x) is increasing on $[0,b]$. 
What would be the general properties of $g(x)$ which satisfy the aformentioned assumptions. Are there any possibilities for g(x) except a linear function?

So far, I have found that a linear function is an option for $g(x)$ such as $g(x)=\alpha x$. I am looking for all the possibilities!!

Comment: Pick any bounded, strictly positive continuous function $u(x)$ such that $\forall x,\ \lvert u(x)\rvert<\frac ab$. For instance, $$u(x)=\frac{a}{b\pi}\left(\frac\pi2+\arctan x\right)$$ Then, $$g(x)=\int_0^x u(t)\,dt$$ makes $h$ a strictly monotone decreasing function. **All** possibilities might be undescriptive.

Comment: I have two questions regarding your answer; 1) what is the domain of x, is it equal to [0,b] or not?  2) $|u(x)|<\frac{a}{b}$ or $|u(x)-\frac{a}{b}|>0 $?

Comment: 1) In the example, the domain is $\Bbb R$, so it can be restricted to $[0,b]$. 2) Actually, I should have written $0<u(x)<\frac ab$ (which is satisfied by the example). I wonder why I had put an absolute value there.

Comment: What would be wrong if $u(x)>\frac{a}{b}$? Do you think $u(x)$ should be bounded, strictly positive ?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, in general $g(x)$ might not even be differentiable, so $u$ might not even exist. Point is that, as soon as you find a positive continuous function $u$ such that the sign of $u(x)-\frac ab$ never changes, the integral of $u$ is a good candidate for $g$. Of course, if $u(x)$ is always greater than $\frac ab$, $h(x)$ will be monotonically increasing.